# How to Paste an Asset file to a granted Directory in Android?

Tags: android, android-external-storage, android-assets

I'm creating an app which pastes a file in a game's android data folder. But I don't know how to paste asset file after getting directory's access.
Here's my method to request the directory's access:

```
private void requestAccess() {

        StorageManager sm = (StorageManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent();

        String startDir = "Android/data/com.game/file/configuration/xx";

        Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI");

        String scheme = uri.toString();

        intent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);


        scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/");

        startDir = startDir.replace("/", "%2F");

        scheme += "%3A" + startDir;

        uri = Uri.parse(scheme);


        intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri);


        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

}

The code above works and I am able to get Directory's access but I don't know how to paste any Asset file from onActivityResult method.

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Granted Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       

        if (data != null){
            Uri dataUri = data.getData();
            if (dataUri.getPath().endsWith("Android")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result:" + dataUri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                final int flags = data.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION;
                getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(dataUri, flags);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Path", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            


        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: `The code above works and I am able to get Directory's access` No. ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT creates... a document and you get access to that document. Not to the directory it is in.

Comment: @blackapps so which intent category should I use for this?

Comment: Did you change your code? I now see .createOpenDocumentTreeIntent(). And that gives you access to a whole directory.

Comment: You confused me with intent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT). Which does not make sense at all. Better remove.

Comment: @blackapps I removed that but what after that? How do I paste the raw file now?

Comment: Well it is pretty standard to create a new file with DocumentFile.createFile once you got an uri for a directory from createOpenDocumentTreeIntent(). And once you created the file you can open an output stream for it and write the bytes fom your assets file to it.

Comment: I dont understand why you speak of pasting as i would rather think you wanna make a copy of the file.

Comment: @blackapps I have an .ini extension file so what should be the mime type when I'm creating a new file from DocumentFile.createFile?

Comment: I always put `"*/*"` for any file. Otherwise for an .in i would use `"text/plain"`.

Comment: Can you help me out with outputStream on created file? I'm getting confused.

Comment: I see no code where you create a new file. Start with that. We wait... You can remove the requestAccess() code as its pretty irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Use IO api write to destination file

e.g:
Step 1, read assets file to InputStream

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("assets_file_name");
```

Step 2, write InputStream to Destination File, also you can use [FileIOUitls](https://github.com/Blankj/AndroidUtilCode/blob/master/lib/utilcode/src/main/java/com/blankj/utilcode/util/FileIOUtils.java) to do this

```
FileIOUtils.writeFileFromIS(desFilePath, is);
```